# Is it possible to use positional, rather than named, parameters in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have created a working target in my `Makefile`, called `test-path-testname`:

```
## Runs tests that match a file pattern and test name to speed up test time
test-path-testname: ensure-env
    docker-compose run -p 9229:9229 \
      -e TYPEORM_URL=postgres://postgres@postgres/someapp_test \
      -e DATABASE_URL_READONLY=postgres://postgres@postgres/someapp_test \
      server npm run test-all -t $(path) -- \
      --detectOpenHandles --watchAll --verbose=false -t "$(testname)" 
.PHONY: test-path-testname
```

It functions perfectly, using the `path` and `testname` parameters:

```
make path=usersArea testname="should create a new user" test-path-testname
```

However that command quite long - **is there way I can use positional, rather than named, parameters in a `Makefile`?**

For example, I'd like to be able to run the above with:

```
make usersArea "should create a new user" test-path-testname
```

Comment: It's not quite accurate to consider these as "named parameters".  What they really are, are make variable assignments that appear on the command line.  I don't know if that helps understand the behavior any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible because all non-options that do not contain a `=` are treated as targets.

Edit after your comment with the motivation explained:

You are solving an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Instead of more variables, pick apart the target name `$@` with substitutions:

```
test-path-testname:
    @echo path=$(word 2,$(subst -, ,$@)) testname=$(word 3,$(subst -, ,$@))
    docker-compose ... -t $(word 3,$(subst -, ,$@)) ...
```

This assumes there are exactly two hyphens in the target name.

Comment: Thanks! Happy to mark this as the accepted answer, as the first sentence explains why. The 'I would not like it' is a bit off topic though.

Comment: @mikemaccana Fair enough. But what is the advantage of the obfuscation? Less typing? What's your motivation?

Comment: The target name `test-path-testname` is sufficient to imply the purpose of the target. Having the additional named variables `path` and `testname` seems redundant.